# Does custom metadata gets stored in the file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

If I upload a file to firebase storage with a custom data

```
const someCustomMetadata = { customMetadata: {'x': 'xxx',} };
updateMetadata(someRef, someCustomMetadata)
```

and then some user downloads this file by calling a firebase function which returns

```
const [url] = await bucket.file("myFile").getSignedUrl(urlOptions)
```

will that user be able to extract `someCustomMetadata` from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user download a file via a signed URL he/she cannot extract the metadata attached to the file.

For that you would need to call the [`getMetadata()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#getmetadata) method.